# alert() not displaying href value

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I would like some help since I am new to JS
I expect this piece of code to show an alert with the href of the element "aaa" but nothing happens. Could you explain what I am doing wrong?
thanks

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        var xxx = document.getElementById("aaa").href;
        alert(xxx);
    }
    myFunction();
</script>

<a href="Moody'sKMVproject-studentsample2.doc" id="aaa">file word</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please delete this question as it is a duplicate of 
[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

I am sorry for posting .. I am new to JS and I didn't know what to search for in the first place

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script is executed before the a tag is rendered. Put the script tag after the a tag and it should work.

Comment: thanks ... it worked like a charm. Nevertheless I saw many examples with script that refers to tags that are put after the script

Answer (score 1):

The script is executed before the DOM is ready so there is no element with id `aaa`.
You can add the script inside

```
window.load=function(){
function myFunction(){
        var xxx = document.getElementById("aaa").href;
        alert(xxx);
    }
    myFunction();
}
```

You can also define the script tag near closing body tag. In this case the DOM is ready and it will able to find an element with `id`

```
<body>
<a href="Moody'sKMVproject-studentsample2.doc" id="aaa">file word</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        var xxx = document.getElementById("aaa").href;
        alert(xxx);
    }
    myFunction();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The script is just above the element it’s trying to reference. `window.load` doesn’t exist and it should be `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){`…`})`.

Comment: That's more than obvious a duplicate so why the answer and not a close vote?

Comment: @Xufox sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use Developer Console for finding errors (right click page, then Inspect Element).

Anyway, the problem seems to be that your JavaScript is done before you have made the anchor (a) element.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="Moody'sKMVproject-studentsample2.doc" id="aaa">file word</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
    var xxx = document.getElementById("aaa").href;
    alert(xxx);
}
myFunction();
</script>
</body>
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

Just as Patrick said, move the  tag down after  and I think this value of href is what you looking for

```
var xxx = document.getElementById("aaa").getAttribute("href");
```